# Django OAuth custom Authentication class

Tags: oauth, django-rest-framework, django-oauth

Need to override the current authentication view api/v1/**o/token** to add my custom error messages based on username and password.

1.

```
{
    "status = ok  // need to add this
    "access_token": "xxxx",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 60,
    "refresh_token": "xxxxaaaxxxx",
    "scope": "read write"
}
```

2.

```
status = 'not_active'
detail= 'user not activated'
```

3.

```
status = 'error'
detail= 'Incorrect username or password'
```

I want to disable the application create on my production hosting. 
How can I do that.?

Comment: I think I need to make another my own REST call to check the user status based on username if TokenView failed to give token.
Or any best way to do it. ?

Comment: what is your authentication backend? why do you really need a custom authentication backend?

Comment: My backend is simple REST API only for my clients (React web and mobile). I need to check this conditions based on that I will add UI functionality.

Comment: I can make another rest call if the return doesn't has access_token. (consider login failure) and check the user is active. Changing the default behavior is not a good idea ?

Comment: Hi Karesh A, hope your issue is solved. Can u please help me out how can I pass user details (for eg: first_name, last_name) with the token.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create a custom authentication class with Django Rest Framework. Subclass `BaseAuthentication` and override the `.authenticate(self, request)` method.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

class CustomAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        """
        Consider the method validate_access_token() takes an access token,
        verify it and return the User.username if the token is valid else None
        """
        username = validate_access_token(request.META.get('X_ACCESS_TOKEN')) 
        if not username:
            return None #return None if User is not authenticated.

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')

        return (user, None)
```

then change  `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in settings to point to the custom authentication class

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'api.core.auth.CustomAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Comment: Hi I was talking about override TokenView inside oauth provider.

Comment: The answer is not relevant to the question asked. The question is about `django-oauth-toolkit`